# How to configure DI container based on CommandLineUtils runtime settings?

Tags: c#, .net-core, command-line-arguments, commandlineutils

I'm migrating a command line application over to using https://github.com/natemcmaster/CommandLineUtils for command line handling (previously known as `Microsoft.Extensions.CommandLineUtils`). It's going quite nice (though the library is quite opinionated) but I'm struggling how to handle options that would influence what/how I inject into my container - namely, how to configure the logger.

As this is for a `dotnet` global tool, I'm trying to follow what the command line does, in terms of options, quite closely.

I've got this on my `CommandBase`:

```
[Option(CommandOptionType.SingleValue,
  ShortName = "v", LongName = "verbosity",
  Description = "Sets the verbosity level of the command. Allowed values are quiet, minimal, normal, detailed.")]
protected LogLevel Verbosity { get; } = LogLevel.Normal;
```

Now, previously, I would parse the command line first, then build my container based on this, then start the command to run.

```
// settings coming from old parsing logic
var container = ContainerRegistration.Init(settings);
var app = new CommandLineApplication<Program> {ThrowOnUnexpectedArgument = false};
app.Conventions.UseDefaultConventions().UseConstructorInjection(container);
return app.Execute(args);
```

I can invert it (as `CommandLineUtils` expects - so IoC container is built first, then `.Execute` is called and parses the command line) for most things, but I'm lost how to configure logging.

Any ideas how to register IoC objects based on `CommandLineUtils` parse results? Or examples of `dotnet` applications doing this?

Comment: Can you share what you want the `Program` constructor and/or subcommand types to look like?